# why can't array_search find the value if the code of the key is "gb2312"?

Tags: php, arrays

my questions:

```
$state=array("你"=>1); 
if(array_key_exists("你",$state)) 
{ 
$result = array_search("你",$state);echo $result;
}else
{
echo "No Exists";
}
```

i expect the result of "1", however the output is "No Exists", i don't know why the program can't get the value of the key "你".

Comment: print_r($state) to see if your array key is being saved like you expect it to. I do not have that charset installed on my computer otherwise I would surely look for that

Comment: I get empty result, not "No Exists", because `array_search()` searches values, not keys.

Comment: Use array_key_exists instead of array_search

Comment: the return value of the array_key_exists("你",$state) is false, i don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

[`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-search.php) will search the given array by value. Try the following:

```
$state = array("你"=>1); 
if(array_key_exists("你", $state))  { 
  echo $state["你"];
} else {
  echo "No Exists";
}

// => 1
```

[» demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/54sEwX)

Comment: thank you . I test the your code in my machine and it outputs "No Exists", so the return value of array_key_exists function is false.  however, if i use the var_dump function ,such as var_dump($state), the result is "你"=>1.  i doubt whether it is related to the coding of "你".

Comment: @wangjue It's really difficult to debug this kind of problem. As you mentioned, it could be a encoding problem. You can try using `json_encode($state)` to have a quick look at what codepoints are used for your string. For me, the above is: `{"\u4f60":1}`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below function will help.

```
<?php
    $array = array('arr1'=>array('find_me'=>'yes you did.'));

    function get_value_by_key($array,$key)
    {
        foreach($array as $k=>$each)
        {
            if($k==$key)
            {
                return $each;
            }

            if(is_array($each))
            {
                if($return = get_value_by_key($each,$key))
                {
                    return $return;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    echo get_value_by_key($array,'find_me');
?>
```

Comment: i know answer has nothing to do with array_search but atleast this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
the encoding type of  the show paper and the store paper  is GB2312.


    $state=array("你"=>1);   
    if(array_key_exists("你",$state)) 
    { 
    $result1 = $state["你"];
         echo $result1;  // can get the value  111
    }else
    {
    echo "No Exists";
    }
```

the code above can be executed rightly.  i can't show my problems accurately. Now i paste out my code , there is some questions.

```
<?php
  $file = file("GB2312-HanZiBianMa.txt");  // file encoding type ANSI 
   foreach ($file  as $line_num => $line)
    {
    list($no,$hex,$dec) = preg_split('[\t]',htmlspecialchars($line));;
    $result[$hex] = $dec;
    }
  $result_2 = array_flip($result);
 if(array_key_exists("你",$result_2))   // **can't find the value** 222
    { 
    $state= $result_2["你"];
    echo $state."<br/>";
    }else
    {
    echo "No Exists<br/>";
    }

foreach($result_2 as $k=>$each)   //can get the value using the preg_match  
        {
         if(preg_match('/你/', $k))
            echo $k."\t".$each."<br/>";     
        }   
  ?>



  the format of GB2312-HanZiBianMa.txt is as follows:
    1947    c4e3    你
    1948    c4e4    匿
    1949    c4e5    腻
    1950    c4e6    逆
```

if your want to test the code , you can save the php code  and save the GB2312.. file. 
   the question is: 
  why can't the following function get the right value ? the data  comes from file and one stores together.

```
if(array_key_exists("你",$result_2))   // **can't find the value** 222
    { 
    $state= $result_2["你"];
    echo $state."<br/>";
    }else
    {
    echo "No Exists<br/>";
    }
```